# I have stayed vs I stayed

Tags: grammar

I never really understood if there is any difference between those sentences:

- I have stayed at the hotel
- I stayed at the hotel
- I have never had any problem with him
- I never had any problem with him

Thank you

Comment: It should be "stayed at the hotel", not "stayed to the hotel".

Comment: And I think 3 is correct, not 4

Comment: What about "I had a stay at the hotel" as compared to 1 & 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This use of the present perfect indicates a *life experience* of some kind.  It says that you have the experience of doing something, in the past.  Examples:

> I have eaten oysters many times.
>
> I have been to Japan.
>
> I have written several novels, and many newspaper articles.

All of your examples are correct, however #2 "I stayed at the hotel" has a different meaning from the others.  The simple past indicates a particular event occurred.  Of course it *implies* that you have the experience, but the context is a simple statement of action, and does not make the experience the focus of the sentence.

Example:

> I stayed at that hotel when I was in Washington DC to testify before Congress.
>
> I have stayed at that hotel in Washington DC, but I didn't think the service was very good.