# I've stayed vs I've stayed in vs at I've stayed

Tags: prepositions

I got this question from an English app :

> I've been to many hotels but this one is by far the best ___. I'd
> definitely recommend it.
>
> The options are:
>
> A) at I've stayed
>
> B) I've stayed
>
> C) I've stayed in

Since the app doesn't provide the answer (it's an app to discover my English level) I can only guess the answer.

In my opinion the answer is C. I've tried to translate the question into my native language and then reversed the translation back into English. Google Translate put the proposition in after stayed. So, that's my answer.

However I've seen many people use I've stayed at the hotel bla bla bla. And according to this [discussion](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/126479/i-have-stayed-vs-i-stayed), it seems like I've stayed **at** the hotel is appropriate. So what's the answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either preposition **at** or **in** when talking about a hotel. In A, the preposition is before the verb: in C is is after the verb. The preposition must be after the verb.

1. A is incorrect because the preposition is in the wrong place.
2. B is incorrect because there is no preposition.
3. C is correct

Answer (score 4):

1. "stay *at* this hotel" / "stay *in* this hotel": Both "at" and "in" are equally valid in this context.
2. Looking at the quiz choices, let's eliminate the wrong answers.

   - Option B, "The best I've stayed," doesn't work because it treats "stay" as a [transitive verb](https://academicguides.waldenu.edu/writingcenter/grammar/verbs), and this meaning of "stay" isn't one. You don't "stay a hotel," you "stay *at* or *in* a hotel."
   - Option A moves the preposition "at" out of order. If you said "the best *at which* I've stayed, that would be grammatical, but might sound a bit stilted.
   - Option C is idiomatically fine. If there had been an option D, "the best I've stayed at," that would have been equally fine. Note, you might hear that you're not supposed to end a sentence with a preposition. By that rule, this option would be a mistake, but it's a common usage, and that "rule" is widely agreed to be obsolete (and never well founded to begin with).